# Node js sync between different machines

Tags: node.js

I need to sync data between Node.js instances on different devices.
For example, if I define an object on machine 1 it needs to be available also on machine n. I can't use anything like Redis or additional software, it has to be pure Node.js.

Is there anything out there? My google searches didn't help much.

Comment: Are you looking for a library ? An architecture ? A protocol ?

Comment: How exactly should this work? Should devices connect to each other somehow? Or is there a server? There's no magic pill, and additional software (Redis, message brokers, whatever) exists because it's not a trivial task.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider to include a [mcve] to narrow down the problem and help people to experiment and understand what you need exactly. See also the guide on [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am developing for a closed platform. The only thing I can do is use node js and install npms. Actually, I am already working on a solution. Objects are defined with Proxy and each time there is a change they are serialized and sent to the other side through a WebSocket connection.

Answer (score 0):

Most applications that need to share the same object across multiple instances of the backend service (in your case, a Node.js-based service), use a database or a database-like system that the backend service talks to. A client request would reach your Node.js service, and it would look up an object requested by the user, or modify it, or delete it, depending on the request. The database could be SQL (e.g. MySQL/PostgreSQL/SQL server), NoSQL (e.g. Cassandra, MongoDB, Riak, etc.), or even an in-memory system like Redis or Memcache (not strictly databases, because they don't provide persistence guarantees). Or you could use a database like [YugaByte DB](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/quick-start/install/) if you need multiple NoSQL/SQL/cache APIs with full persistence in your app and don't want to maintain multiple databases.